# Firefox right-click "Search with ..." on key shortcut

Tags: firefox, search, shortcuts, hotkeys, right-click

When I right-click on the highlighted text in Firefox, it shows an option "Search "text" with Google".
Is it possible to set this option on key shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the solutions I've found require some sort of addon, but in my opinion, the least invasive method involves using [keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension).

To set it up:

1. Install Keyconfig (through the link, I don't believe it can be installed from Get Addons)
2. Open Keyconfig (via options in Extensions) and add a new key. Call it "Search selected text" or something you can identify, and put the following in the the code section:

   var selectedText = getBrowserSelection();
   if (selectedText) {BrowserSearch.loadSearchFromContext(selectedText);}

Hit okay, then find your key in the list and assign it whatever shortcut you'd like by clicking the box next to "apply" and pressing your key combination.

Source: [instructions from "Add Search for Selectin into Edit menu" addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-search-for-selection/?src=search)

Comment: @Roman If you find an answer useful, you should upvote or accept the answer. That's the green checkmark at the left

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Learned a bit more about Firefox myself by looking up a solution :)